# Gratis volume booster for Windows

Tags: windows, gratis, audio, windows-10, volume-control

### 1. Problem

I watch any film from Internet in any browser. Sometimes, sounds in my browser all the same silent, that I can't listen to sounds from movies, without straining.

It would be nice, if would be possible gratis solution of this problem.

---

### 2. Expected behavior

For example, I install and run [**Letasoft Sound Booster**](http://www.letasoft.com/) → I can increase volume to 500%.

[image: Letasoft]

It corrects works for me, but Letasoft Sound Booster is a commercial program, not gratis.

#### 1. Desirable requirements

It would be nice, if gratis solution will be simple as in Letasoft Sound Booster.

---

### 3. Not helped

1. I increase to maximum volume in my operating system.
2. I increase to maximum volume in video player in my browser.
3. I increase to maximum volume in my dynamic.
4. Right-click to sound icon in taskbar → `Open Volume Mixer` → I increase all volume sliders to maximum.

   [image: Sliders]
5. [**All alternatives for Letasoft Sound Booster in AlternativeTo are commercial**](http://alternativeto.net/software/letasoft-sound-booster/).
6. Googling. I find [**Equalizer APO**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/equalizerapo/), but it doesn't help me.

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Please, not dot offer solutions for separate video players in PC (for example, VLC). I think, that downloading all videos, that I want to watch, to PC, is not a good idea.
2. Please, do not offer solutions for separate web-players. Videos, that I watch, can be on different video players.
3. I don't need equalizer or others complicated means for working with sounds. I need increase the volume.

Comment: How about external speakers with a volume control - not gratis but will produce a lot better results.

Comment: Have you tried installing the driver?